# Python and tkinter (buttons)

Tags: python, tkinter

im doing simple GUI calculator.I have buttons with the numbers from 0-9.I store all the numbers and aritnmetic symbols in a string named caluclations.I have a function which is doing the following:

```
newString = ""
newString += calculations
newString += (here is the button text(for example if button1 was clicked i will add to newString "1")
return newString
```

I want when i press a button, to call the function and return the newString to the calculations string.Any ideas?

Comment: "any ideas" is too broad and off topic for this site. Have you done any research? There are dozens of questions on this site related to buttons and calculators, and the method of associating buttons with functions is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function on a button press first you have to create the function like so;

```
def Foo():
    print("Bar")
```

then when you create the button you specify that you want it to execute that function when its pressed, like so;

```
from tkinter import ttk

my_button= ttk.Button(self, text = "button", command = Foo)
```

but if you want to pass parameters to this, which in your example you probably will you do it like this;

```
def Foo(bar):
    print(bar)

my_button_paramaters= ttk.Button(self, text = "button", command = lambda: Foo(paramater))
```

Comment: Your final example is a bit vague and won't work if `parameter` is something that isn't a constant.